# How to test a flash detection script without uninstalling flash player?

Tags: flash, detection

I´m using the Flash Player Detection Kit. Is there a Firefox add-on, some plugin or software to toggle between Flash-Non Flash for testing purposes of this script?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to Add-Ons->Plugins and turn off Flash.

Answer (score 1):

The QuickJava extension puts an array of buttons in the FireFox status bar that lets you enable/disable flash, java, javascript, or silverlight.